# javascript $ not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage where i want to have collapsible headings,
I have the below code as an example but for some reason it keeps saying that $ is not defined.

```
<head>
<style>
tr, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.header
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0">
<script>
'use strict';
$('.header').click(function(){

$(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
</script>
  <tr  class=".header">
   <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class=".header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I am wanting when the page loads you just get a list of the headers and then when you click on one it expands

Comment: you haven't included jquery

Comment: I will presume that David is new to the world of web dev, so to down vote this is just cruel. The guy is at least trying.

Comment: @gmann1982 you're right, there are people here that downvote for anyreason.... they should see that he put the code, he explained the question and said the error that he was getting, mcve was ok... but people arent supportive anymore.

Answer (score 6):

try adding jquery:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, you dont prefix classes with `.` in the html, only in selectors, so change  `class=".header"` to  `class="header"`.

Best practices aside, [here's a jsfiddle showing the code working](http://jsfiddle.net/4ns5naax/), you just need to load the lib and run the script once it (and the dom) are loaded

Comment: I would consider placing the script tag at the bottom of the body instead of in the head. Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup).

Comment: no its still not working saying $ is not defined

Comment: can you update the code in your question and show where you've put the script etc. theres no reason why it shouldnt work if included correctly

Comment: @Gideon considering the level of complexity in this question/issue I think perf best practices are too much

Comment: Not sure waht the issue was, but when i put the javascript into an external file and referenced it in the HTML it worked

Comment: glad you managed to resove it

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, did you check that jQuery exists before call your script ?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can check if jQuery is available with the following method for example :

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
// jQuery is loaded  
} else {
// jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The $ is a shorthand for the library jQuery so you must import it to the page,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been said: You should add jQuery, like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The reason is: You obviously found some jQuery example somewhere and are trying to make it work.
Without the jQuery libraries, though, `$.*` has no meaning. It gets the meaning only through the jQuery library.

To learn more, head over to [the jQuery website](https://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the jQuery library before you start using it within your JavaScript. I recommend putting it just above your body tag to improve loading times.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <!-- Usual head stuff -->
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- Alot of nice HTML and such -->

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And if you want to be really sure about if jQuery is loaded, you can do something like Carlos Delgado suggests: an if statements what checks if jQuery has been imported.